# Hot Restart on Flutter web gives exception in console to load images Failed to execute measure on performance The mark 24listenerbegin doesn't exist

Tags: flutter, web-applications, hybrid-mobile-app

```
    dart-sdk/lib/developer/timeline.dart 295:10                             finish
packages/flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart 434:13                   <fn>
packages/flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart 440:28                   listener
packages/flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart 711:25                  setImage
packages/flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart 1061:5                  [_emitFrame]
packages/flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart 1040:7                  _decodeNextFrameAndSchedule
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50      <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                    runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 162:18                              handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 846:44                              handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 875:13                              _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 647:5                               [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 721:7                               callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                        _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                         _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:7      <fn>
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Another exception was thrown: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'measure' on 'Performance': The mark '24-listener-begin' does not exist.
Another exception was thrown: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'measure' on 'Performance': The mark '25-listener-begin' does not exist.
Another exception was thrown: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'measure' on 'Performance': The mark '26-listener-begin' does not exist.
Another exception was thrown: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'measure' on 'Performance': The mark '27-listener-begin' does not exist.
Another exception was thrown: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'measure' on 'Performance': The mark '28-listener-begin' does not exist.
Another exception was thrown: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'measure' on 'Performance': The mark '29-listener-begin' does not exist.
Another exception was thrown: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'measure' on 'Performance': The mark '30-listener-begin' does not exist.
`your text`Another exception was thrown: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'measure' on 'Performance': The mark '31-listener-begin' does not exist.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTp5h.png)

Project Structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtmUP.png)

pubspec.yaml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQCtK.png)

The Image should display properly each time.

Comment: Please share code as `code` and not as images. Also, please clearify your question so others can help you better